# How do I update a database I distribute with an iOS app, without updating the app itself?

Tags: ios

I am building an application where the users can download cooking recipes. Each recipe is accompanied with image. The db will be Sqlite and it will be deployed locally on the users device. I plan to put all the images inside the "Supported Files" folder which will be used by the local database.

My question is that how will I update the images without having to push out a new version. Let's say I add a new recipe to my server database and I want users to have that recipe how will I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a API to request the current recipes version, that you can use to check for updates. Example:

```
 http://api.mysite.com/isCurrentVersion?v=0.0.5
```

That can return a HTTP response code that tells you to update the images / database you have cached, or you can simply can use php to echo a number of the current version, and do string matching client side, like this:

```
 NSString *downloadedVersion = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"version"];
 NSString *serverVersion = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.mysite.com/currentVersion"]];

 if ([downloadedVersion caseInsensitiveCompare:serverVersion])
      // download the new version
```

Server code:

```
 <?php
    echo "current_version_number" 
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! But is there a way to download images into the iPhone documents folder without having update the app through iTunes. Images are not in the database but only the name of the image will be in the database.

Comment: @azamsharp yes, just put the images in a zip file on your server, and download & unzip them with the database. There are quite a few good zip libraries available in objective-c

Answer (score 0):

Have your app query the server once in a while to see whether any of the pictures have changed since it last updated. I'd suggest having the app send a list of filenames with their mtimes, and have the server send back a list of stale files.  Your app can then fetch the new files, replacing the old ones.